# Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") equivalent in angular

Tags: angular

There are ways to create new GUID in angular but what is the equivalent of this C# function call in angular

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
```

to get GUID in this format `b37f986288fc4cac93c439f47d6a802b`

Is there any standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

using [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4):

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const uuid = uuidv4().replace(/-/g, '');
```